# How to setup docker swarm in distributed server?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have set up single host docker deployment using docker-compose. But now I have 4 server instances running on vultr each one has different services running. 
For example,

Server 1: mongodb

Server 2: node/express

Server 3: redux

Server 4: load balancer

How can I connect all these services using docker swarm?

Comment: On Production, you should use docker swarm + docker stack instead. Use 1 server to be a manager one. Init swarm mode on your manager server by open necessary ports, connect other servers into swarm network as workers. On manager server, manipulate docker stack to install services on any workers (using node id) or just need to deploy your stack then let docker swarm handle the schedule stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should create swarm of nodes using [docker swarm init](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_init/) and [docker swarm join](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_join/). Each node is docker engine installed on a different host. If you have just 4 hosts you can decide that all nodes will be [managers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/nodes/).
- Then you should deploy [docker stack](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack/) which will deploy your docker
  services (mongodb, etc...) using the `docker-compose.yml` file: `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml`
- Docker services will run on all nodes according to the number of
  replicas you specify when you create each service.
- If you want each service to run on specific node, assign [labels](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_update/#add-label-metadata-to-a-node) for
  each node and add [service constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint).